# How to disable Facebook push notifications in iPad 2

Tags: ios, ipad, facebook

I have an iPad 2 with iOS 4 and the Facebook for iPad app installed.

Even after disabling all the `Push Notifications` from `Settings > Facebook > Push Notifications`, I still get push notifications.

Is this a bug in either Facebook or Apple's part or is there a hidden setting somewhere to disable the notifications?

Comment: Have you tried an uninstall - reinstall?

Comment: Yes. I've tried that but still it keeps coming up.

Comment: Sorry there isn't a lot more I can suggest, hopefully you will find the answer. Would you consider upgrading to iOS5?

Answer (score 4):

There were some bugs in the FB app for notifications, but you should be able to disable the notifications on an app-by-app basis in at the iOS level from `Settings -> General -> Notifications` (or `Settings -> Notifications` ... I don't have an iOS 4 device handy to double-check).

Comment: I'm not sure as I could not find any settings for `notifications` under `Setting>General>Notification`. Instead, on the left pane itself, scrolling down, there's a section called 'Apps' under which Facebook App is listed, inside which I'd disabled the push notifications. So the path is like `Settings>Facebook>Push Notifications`. But still the problem is there.

Comment: I think the iPad has a 'Notifications' section in the left pane (I think it was there in iOS 4), if you select that, you should be able to toggle off the notifications from Facebook completely.  The settings found under the Facebook app section will only take effect after you have opened the app after changing them, but I've always found these to be quite unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to ALSO go to Settings->Notifications within the iPad app and turn off Notifications there AS WELL.